# Retrofit2 OAuth2 with Client ID and Client secret key in Android - 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, retrofit2

When i try to get token with client id, client secret key and authorization code with help of retrofit. I'm getting **401 UnAuthorized error**

**MainActivity.kt**

```
if (appLinkData != null && appLinkData.toString().startsWith("https://abc.abconline.com/plugin/callback")) {
        val code = appLinkData.getQueryParameter("code")
        //     Toast.makeText(this, code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val builder = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://abc.abcOnline.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
        val client = builder.create(restClient::class.java)
        client.getAccessToken(
            clientId,
            clientSecret,
            code,
            "Authorization"
        ).enqueue(object : Callback<AccessToken> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AccessToken>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Falied: $t.message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<AccessToken>, response: Response<AccessToken>) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    response.body().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
```

**RestClient.kt**

```
interface restClient {

@POST("/oauth2/token")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun getAccessToken(
@Field("client_id") clientId: String,
@Field("client_secret") clientSecret: String,
@Field("code") code: String,
@Field("grant_type") grantType: String,
@Field("redirect_uri") redirectUri: String
): Call<AccessToken>
```

}

How I can fix it?
I am spending a lot of time to figure out...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**It's not the problem with Retrofit, Server is returning its response 401**
 means call is successful but there might be a problem with "Credentials" or insufficient " Privileges", Use **POSTMAN** for testing if the response is Succesful then implement it.

have a look at [401-unauthorized-error](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/401-unauthorized-error)

hope it helps.

Comment: With POSTMAN everything working fine. I can generate token and use it... but when I try to generate through program I am getting 401 error for generating token

Comment: have you used Volley?

Answer (score 0):

As a general point, integrating Open Id Connect into a mobile app is not easy. There are many tricky aspects related to usability and reliability. I think you should be looking for these qualities:

- The ability to view API and OAuth messages
- Use a mainstream and respected security library

If it helps I have some resources here that may help you to compare against, and a code sample you can run. Maybe you can adapt Retrofit around this type of solution?

- [Kotlin AppAuth Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android)
- [Android Code Sample Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)
- [Android HTTPS Debugging Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/21/android-https-debugging/)